# Accidentally disconnected LG K7 during the firmware update

Tags: updates, lg

I accidentally disconnected LG K7 during the firmware update and I don't know what to do. I was on a phone call when I left it to charge my laptop and I wanted to move the phone to another charger that's near my bed. I didn't see that it was doing an update and I'm scared that I have messed up big this time. Please help.

Comment: Was the firmware update initiated from the laptop, or over the air (OTA)? Did the phone shut down while it was doing the update? Finally, did the update complete? Otherwise, I don't think there's anything to worry about.

Comment: computer but i droped my phone and now had to replace it